# Why we need to put parenthesis when giving a template type

Tags: c++, templates

Hello I am trying to understand this piece of code:

```
vector<int> a = {5, 3, 6, 1, 7};
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater<int>());
for(int i : a) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
```

Why I need to put parenthesis after the greater. This greater is a structure defined which is like this:

```
/// One of the @link comparison_functors comparison functors@endlink.
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct greater : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
    {
      _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
      bool
      operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
      { return __x > __y; }
    };
```

This is defined in `stl_function.h` in c++. Now I think the way it works is that I give a new type or template for this. The comparing file will make an object of this and then through `operator overloading`, `()` it will do object_name(int_value_1, int_value_2) and this returns a bool and all is understandable. But why these `()` when I am sending this in template. Is there some flaw in the way I think this is implemented?

PS: I said object which is a class specific term but I think in structures, it may be called that way in c++.

Comment: The parentheses signify that the constructor is called, i. e. you create an instance of this struct. For comparison: If you wanted to call the operator on such a newly created (temporary) object, it would look like `greater<int>()(10, 12)`.

Comment: OK makes sense. Then its an object just like new World() in java. It's made but with no name and just passed as the third template? Then typename _Compare contains a reference to an object  in memory?

Comment: Roughly – apart from the wording not being precise, it's the third function parameter of type of second template parameter, Java's new ressembles much C++'s one, just that in C++ the pointer is explicit, in java implicit, and C++ has no automatic/implicit memory management (garbage collection).

Comment: It's not really like `new World()` in Java. Be careful of Java analogies; they often lead to trouble in C++. In C++, `new World()` creates an object on the free store and gives you a pointer to that object. In C++ you'd have to delete that object afterwords.

Comment: Yeah thank I got it. new World() will be taken up by the garbage collector and is actually address of object while new in c++ gives an object reference and I need to delete it. Thank you man you are awesome. I got it. But is this () a syntax to create objects because otherwise I think it like: greater<int> a;

Comment: Not a reference, a pointer... C++ knows both references and pointers, and they differ in many respects (from point of view of the user/coder; technically – if the reference is instantiated at all – you won't be able to distinguish one from another in compiled code).

Comment: Is this some new syntax to create object greater<int>()

Comment: This is general syntax to create temporary objects, unrelated to templates. Like `std::string()`. Similarly for local variables, but in this case you need to drop the parenthteses (`std::greater<int> g/*() skip!*/;`), otherwise it would be a function declaration. On the other hand, if you pass arguments to, you need them again, e. g. `std::vector<int> v(7);`. For comparison: `std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>()` – note the asterisk specifying a pointer type. You usually wouldn't create vectors this way, though.

Comment: More comfortable: `auto instance = new SomeType();`, avoids type repetition.

Comment: Thank you sir. It's been a productive discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why we need to put parenthesis when giving a template type
> sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater());

`std::greater` is a class template. `std::greater<int>` is an instance of that class template, and is a type (more specifically, a class type). `std::greater<int>()` is a temporary object (an instance of the type that is the instance of the template). The parentheses are syntax for value initialisation.

It is not possible to pass a type as an argument to a function (however, it would be possible to pass a type as a template argument to a function template).  It is possible to pass a temporary object as an argument to a function.

So, we use the parentheses so that an object is created that we pass as an argument.

> PS: I said object which is a class specific term but I think in structures, it may be called that way in c++.

If by structure you mean a struct: Structs are classes (that have been declared with the class-key `struct`).

Instances of all types are objects in C++.

Comment: Why we are not passing in an object like in nth_element(iterator, iterator, iterator, comp);

Comment: In set we cannot pass a function but we can in nth_element why?

Comment: @ShobhitTewari `Why we are not passing in an object` We are. `std::greater<int>()` is an object. `In set we cannot pass a function` We can pass a function to the set constructor, if we use a function pointer of compatible type as the template type parameter of the comparator for the set.