# STL and std custom compare arguments working in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, set, function-object

I asked this question on stackoverflow [STL passing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961986/why-we-need-to-put-parenthesis-when-giving-a-template-type)

I got to know that we pass objects which in tern call the compare operator in them and compare our values and gives us a result. All good.

Now in this piece of code:

```
class Compare {
    public:
    bool operator ()(const int &a, const int &b) { return a < b;}
};

void solve(){
    set<int, Compare> s;
    vector<int> arr = {1,4,6,3,7,2,8,588,5};    
    for(int e : arr) s.insert(e);
    for(auto it = s.rbegin();it!=s.rend();it++) cout << *it << ' '; cout << endl;
}
```

I get error if I do `Compare()` which is what I thought must be done(passing an object). Why so? How can we pass Compare?

Also in this piece of code I cannot pass a function like:

```
bool comp(const int &a, const int &b) { return a < b; }

void solve(){
    set<int, comp> s;
    vector<int> arr = {1,4,6,3,7,2,8,588,5};    
    for(int e : arr) s.insert(e);
    for(auto it = s.rbegin();it!=s.rend();it++) cout << *it << ' '; cout << endl;
}
```

Which is what I expect. Not passing functions.

Now in this piece of code:

```
bool comp(const int &a, const int &b) { return a < b; }

void solve(){
    vector<int> arr = {1,4,6,3,7,2,8,588,5};    
    nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+3, arr.end(), comp);
    for(int e : arr) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

I am able to pass a function and there is no error. I mean what is going on? From my perspective, we should just pass objects and they will call their () overloaded operator and compare values but sometimes we are passing functions, sometimes passing objects giving error and sometimes we just pass class name. What is exactly going on in c++

Comment: Can you provide the error message for each case?

Comment: A lot of error like function returning function. no known conversion for argument 2 from 'Compare' to 'bool'. Etc etc but basically saying I can't compare the way I am doing it

Comment: the STL is a library that was the predecessor of the c++ standard library. Your title suggests that you are talking about both, the STL and the standard library, but I think you mean the standard library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet the compiler issues an error because you was using an object Compare() as the type template argument instead of the type Compare.

If you will write for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Compare {
    public:
    bool operator ()(const int &a, const int &b) const { return a < b;}
};

int main() 
{
    set<int, Compare> s( ( Compare() ) );
    
    vector<int> arr = {1,4,6,3,7,2,8,588,5};    
    for(int e : arr) s.insert(e);
    for(auto it = s.rbegin();it!=s.rend();it++) cout << *it << ' '; cout << endl;   

    return 0;
}
```

then the program compiles successfully and its output is

```
588 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

That is as the second type template argument of the class template `std::set` you need to use the type specifier Compare. But if you want to specify the argument of the constructor you need to use an object of the type of the template argument.

The same problem exists for the second code snippet. You need to write like it is shown in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

bool comp(const int &a, const int &b) { return a < b; }

int main() 
{
    set<int, bool ( * )( const int &, const int & )> s( comp );
    
    vector<int> arr = {1,4,6,3,7,2,8,588,5};    
    for(int e : arr) s.insert(e);
    for(auto it = s.rbegin();it!=s.rend();it++) cout << *it << ' '; cout << endl;   return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

Pay attention to that the class template std::set is declared like

```
template <class Key, class Compare = less<Key>, 
          class Allocator = allocator<Key> >
class set;
```

So if you specified explicitly the second template argument (instead of using by default the function object `std::less<Key`>) then you need to provide a corresponding object of this type in a constructor of the class template std::set.

Comment: First one is correct. But if I pass Compare() instead of Compare I get an error

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: `Compare`  is a (class) type. `Compare( )`  is a temporary object of `Compare` type, created by calling the default constructor `Compare::Compare( )`. This ctor does nothing, and is implicitly defined by the compiler for you.

Comment: @ShobhitTewari The template argument specifies a type template argument. The argument of the constructor std::set is an object of the type template argument.

Comment: @MSalters `Compare()` could also be a type (a function type taking no arguments, returning `Compare`). It's not clear how OP uses it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: OP literally wrote `class Compare { ...`

Comment: What's the usage of `set<int, Compare> s( ( Compare() ) );`? `set<int, Compare> s;` is enough, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was mistaken. I updated the post. The argument is used to show the difference between a type and an object of the type.

Answer (score 3):

Second template parameter of `std::set` is a **type**.

You might use function pointer:

```
bool comp(const int &a, const int &b) { return a < b; }

std::set<int, bool (*)(const int &, const int &)> s(comp);
```

Answer (score 2):

`operator()` must be const. That's the API.

```
class Compare {
    public:
    bool operator ()(const int &a, const int &b) const { return a < b; }
}
```

Comment: Even if it's not const, it does not give error. It gives me error in set if I do Compare() instead of Compare. Also the semicolon I am saying that the for loop scope ends here and I am writing a fresh line. I just did it like this as I was focusing on learning,.

Comment: @ShobhitTewari how do you use `Compare()`? You can't do `set<int, Compare()>`, that wouldn't work

Comment: So in set class is it like, whatever type I passed it will create object and then call the overloaded function? If yes I got it. Inside set class somewhere for Compare c; c(a, b)

Comment: @ShobhitTewari: You may want to get a good C++ book. `std::set` is a _class template_. It is instantiated with a _value type_ and optionally with a comparison type that provides the set order. That's two _types_. Some template accept non-type template arguments, but ` std::set` only takes types.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks. It is clear now. The question is which answer to accept as all are correct.